# Efeito do houver não funciona CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web e gostaria que ao passar o mouse os icons mudasse de cor e não mostrar aquela linha embaixo dos icons mas o `houver` não funciona.

HTML

```
  <div class="header-fixed">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-left">
            <div class="icons_moveis"><a class="fa fa-home"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="icons_moveis"><a class="fa fa-user"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-right">
           <div class="icons_moveis"><a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.icons_moveis:hover{

  color: yellow;
 }
```

Pagina com os icons em que ao passar o mouse os icons era pra ficar amarelo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É possível que seja sobreposição de estilos. Já tentou com `color: yellow !important;` ? E o `hover` era suposto ser para o `<div>` que é o que está, ou para o `<a>` ?

Comment: suposto ser para o <div> que é o que está, ou para o <a> não entendi ?

Comment: coloquei color: yellow !important; e não funcionou

Comment: Está a aplicar cor de texto no `<div>` mas os `<a>` provavelmente já tem uma cor definida no estilo. Logo provavelmente o que quer fazer é `.icons_moveis a:hover {`. Mas já depende um pouco de como tem os seus estilos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve setar a cor amarela para o elemento filho (que no seu caso é o elemento a), dentro da div com a classe icons_moveis.

```css
.icons_moveis a:hover{
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
 }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="header-fixed">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-left">
            <div class="icons_moveis"><a class="fa fa-home"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-center">
            <div class="icons_moveis"><a class="fa fa-user"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 text-right">
           <div class="icons_moveis"><a class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```